# MongoDB database disappearing after few hours

Tags: 16.04, ssh, mongodb, aws

In AWS I am using Ubuntu 16.04 instance with MongoDB, node, and express installed, And I create one db named abc and migrate my parse database to it. Everything working fine. but after one day or few hours later my mongo db database disappeared with all data and assigned user.

When i check AWS machine with ssh MongoDB running. I have no idea what's going on.

My mongodb config file

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
net:
  port: 27017
# Desabe due to use with nginx remote access
# bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Have you enabled authentication and properly secured your MongoDB deployment? The configuration file included in your current description does not enable authentication and binds to all IP addresses, so it's possible a remote attacker is connecting and dropping your data. Do you see any any new connections or databases being created outside of those you expect? I recommend reviewing the security measures and referenced tutorials on the [MongoDB Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/).

Comment: So is the directory still there though? What is in var/ lib/ mongodb now? I'm wondering if it has stored it in the ephemeral storage that deletes on reboot.